# How to properly support Int values in CGFloat math in Swift?

Tags: swift, casting, implicit-conversion, implicit-typing

### Goal

I (like many others on the web) would like to use `Int` variables and literals in `CGFloat` math since readability & ease of development outweigh a possible loss in precision by far. This is most noticeable when you use manual layout throughout an app instead of using the Storyboard.

So the following should work without any manual `CGFloat` casts:

```
let a = CGFloat(1)
let b = Int(2)

let c = a / b  // Cannot invoke / with an arguments list of type (CGFloat, Int)
let d = b / a  // Cannot invoke / with an arguments list of type (Int, CGFloat)
let e = a / 2  // => CGFloat(0.5)
let f = 2 / a  // => CGFloat(2.0)
let g = 2 / b  // => Int(1)
let h = b / 2  // => Int(1)
let i = 2 / 2  // => Int(1)
let j: CGFloat = a / b  // Cannot invoke / with an arguments list of type (CGFloat, Int)
let k: CGFloat = b / a  // Cannot invoke / with an arguments list of type (Int, CGFloat)
let l: CGFloat = a / 2  // => CGFloat(0.5)
let m: CGFloat = 2 / a  // => CGFloat(2.0)
let n: CGFloat = 2 / b  // Cannot invoke / with an arguments list of type (IntegerLiteralConvertible, Int)
let o: CGFloat = b / 2  // Cannot invoke / with an arguments list of type (Int, IntegerLiteralConvertible)
let p: CGFloat = 2 / 2  // => CGFloat(1.0)
```

### Approach

Since we cannot add implicit conversions to Swift types I had to add appropriate operators which take `CGFloat` and `Int`.

```
func / (a: CGFloat, b: Int) -> CGFloat { return a / CGFloat(b) }
func / (a: Int, b: CGFloat) -> CGFloat { return CGFloat(a) / b }
```

### Problem

The two operators become ambiguous when Swift tries to implicitly create `CGFloat` values from integer literals. It doesn't know which of the two operands to convert (example case `p`).

```
let a = CGFloat(1)
let b = Int(2)

let c = a / b  // => CGFloat(0.5)
let d = b / a  // => CGFloat(2.0)
let e = a / 2  // => CGFloat(0.5)
let f = 2 / a  // => CGFloat(2.0)
let g = 2 / b  // => Int(1)
let h = b / 2  // => Int(1)
let i = 2 / 2  // => Int(1)
let j: CGFloat = a / b  // => CGFloat(0.5)
let k: CGFloat = b / a  // => CGFloat(2.0)
let l: CGFloat = a / 2  // => CGFloat(0.5)
let m: CGFloat = 2 / a  // => CGFloat(2.0)
let n: CGFloat = 2 / b  // => CGFloat(1.0)
let o: CGFloat = b / 2  // => CGFloat(1.0)
let p: CGFloat = 2 / 2  // Ambiguous use of operator /
```

### Question

Is there any way to declare the operators in a way where there is no ambiguous use and all test cases succeed?

Comment: I'd recommend against creating these operators and explicitly cast in the direction you want to cast... for the sake of future maintenance of any code you think this operator will improve.

Comment: @nhgrif for what reason?

Comment: @nhgrif the code is perfectly readable without explicit casts when you thoroughly name variables. It gets less readable when when formulas are polluted by casts. `.height = (100 * views.count) + 100` is totally fine while `.height = (100 * CGFloat(views.count)) + 100` is totally unnecessary.

Comment: For whatever you're doing there, you should be using auto layout...

Comment: @nhgrif not if I want to develop fast & maintain app performance. Anyway both discussions are off-topic. Swift is supposed to be extensible and this ability is broken here - most likely due to a bug.

Comment: For what it's worth, you run into the same problem if it's not an operator and just a regular function.

Comment: @nhgrif yep, but fortunately that's a rare case.

Comment: I've added an answer which should explain why the short answer to this question is "No", but you should also know that you can do auto-layout even without interface builder...

Answer (score 0):

For starters, **tl;dr: NO**.

---

The problem is that we're asking the compiler to do too much implicitly.

I'm going to use regular functions for this answer, because I want it to be clear that this has nothing to do with operators.

---

So, we need the following 4 functions:

```
func foo(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func foo(a: Int, b: Float) -> Float {
    return 2.0
}

func foo(a: Float, b: Int) -> Float {
    return 3.0
}

func foo(a: Float, b: Float) -> Float {
    return 4.0
}
```

And now we're in the same scenario.  I'm going to ignore all of the ones that work and focus on these two scenarios:

```
let bar1 = foo(1,2)
let bar2: Float = foo(1,2)
```

---

In the first scenario, we're asking Swift to implicitly determine just one thing: What type should `bar1` be?  The two arguments we pass to `foo` are `1`, which is of type `IntegerLiteralConvertible`, and `2`, which is again of the type `IntegerLiteralConvertible`.

Because there is only one override for `foo` which takes two `Int` arguments, Swift is able to figure out what type `bar1` should be, and that's whatever type the `foo(Int,Int)` override returns, which is `Int`.

Now, consider the scenario in which we add the following function:

```
func foo(a: Int, b: Int) -> Float {
    return 5.0
}
```

Now, scenario 1 becomes ambiguous:

```
let bar1 = foo(1,2)
```

We're asking Swift to determine TWO things implicitly here:

1. Which override of `foo` to use
2. What type to use for `bar1`

There is more than one way to satisfy the scenario.  Either `bar1` is an `Int` and we use the `foo(Int,Int)->Int` override, or `bar2` is a `Float`, and we use the `foo(Int,Int)->Float` override.  The compiler can't decide.

We can make the situation less ambiguous though as such:

```
let bar1: Int = foo(1,2)
```

In which case the compiler knows we want the `foo(Int,Int)->Int` override--it's the only one that satisfies the scenario.  Or we can do:

```
let bar2: Float = foo(1,2)
```

In which case the compiler knows we want the `foo(Int,Int)->Float` override--again, the only way to satisfy the scenario.

---

But let's take a look back at my scenario 2, which is exactly the problem scenario you have:

```
let bar2: Float = foo(1,2)
```

There's not a `foo(Int,Int)->Float` override (forget everything about scenario 1 in which we added this override).  However, the type `IntegerLiteralConvertible` can be implicitly cast to different types of numeric data types (only literal integers... not integer variables).  So the compiler will try to find a `foo` override that takes arguments that `IntegerLiteralConvertible` can be cast to and returns a `Float`, which we've explicitly marked as `bar2`'s type.

Well, `IntegerLiteralConvertible` can be cast as a `Float`, so the compiler finds three functions that take some combination of the right argument:

- `foo(Int,Float) -> Float`
- `foo(Float,Int) -> Float`
- `foo(Float,Float) -> Float`

And the compiler doesn't know which to use.  How can it?  Why should it prioritize casting one or the other of your literals integers to a float?

So we get the ambiguity problem.

We can give the compiler another override.  It's the same one we gave it in scenario 2: `foo(Int,Int) -> Float`, and now the compiler is okay with the following:

```
let bar2: Float = foo(1,2)
```

Because in this case, without implicitly casting the `IntegerLiteralConvertibles`, the compiler was able to find a function that matched: `foo(Int, Int) -> Float`.

---

So now you're thinking:

> All right, let me just add this `foo(Int,Int)->Float` and everything will work!

Right?

Well, sorry to disappoint, but given the following two functions:

```
foo(Int,Int) -> Int
foo(Int,Int) -> Float
```

We will still run into ambiguity problems:

```
let bar3 = foo(1,2)
```

There are two overrides for `foo` that take an `Int` (or `IntegerLiteralConvertible`), and because we haven't specified `bar3`'s type and we're asking the compiler both figure out the appropriate override and implicitly determine `bar3`'s type, which it cannot do.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. That's what I expected although I still hope that someone knows a workaround for this language limitation. If not I'll accept the answer in a few days.

Comment: This isn't even a Swift specific problem. It's a problem for any language that allows overloading functions AND implicitly typed variables.